# ReactJS - Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event

Tags: reactjs, event-listener

I have a select menu which has some options in it. I created my project with React JS and I have Foundation.Zurb framework added to my project.

When I click one of the option of select menu, I get this error in the console:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952>

I tried couple solutions but none of them worked. What might be the reason, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding e.preventDefault() inside a onchange function?

Comment: Yeah. Right now I disabled "verbose" option in developer tools and I am not getting that message anymore. I think everything works fine when I change the option but Chrome is warning me about something. Still it took my almost 2-3 hours and it is very disturbing. In case you are also having this message, go to dev tools and go to "Console" section. Then instead of choosing "All Levels" try to disable "Verbose" option.

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2729

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all `scroll` and `touch` events expect to be "passive" if `preventDefault()` is not called. But it's not that easy..

1. Not all browsers support passive event listener option.
2. If it's the 3rd party code that is causing the warning, modifying it's source code is a bad bad practice.
3. Packages like `default-passive-events` jsut blindly apply passive attribute ignoring the usage of `preventDefault()` and that might cause your script break..
4. Applying `passive: false` to all the events will remove the warning, but will not improve the performance. Whats the point then?

I was dealing with such issue not a long ago and created a package that overwrites `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` and add `passive` option to all the events that do not `preventDefault` and if browsers supports it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passive-events-support

This not only removed the warning, but also improved the performance.
Make sure to pass only necessary events instead of default. In this case just 'mousewheel':

```
<script>
  window.passiveEvents = ['mousewheel']
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/passive-events-support/dist/main.js"></script>
```

If you want a modular way, you can find an example in the docs.
Make sure to import this script before any other script that causes that warning.